# Multiply the numbers in a mixed string (SVG path) by a common factor

Tags: c#, .net, string, svg

is there an easy way to multiply all the numbers in a mixed (text and numbers) string by a factor?

I have a SVG-Path, for example: `d = "M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z"`

The string includes couples of number, separated by `,`. Each number can also be a double value. The pairs of numbers represent an x,y-coordinate.

How can I multiply all pairs of numbers in that string for example by the factor of 2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Please include what you expect the result to be in the question.

Comment: What about performance consideration ? Doesn't this notation is a standard one in a tool you use, which already integrates the operators you need ? Naive way to implement what you asked : regex (or not) split the string on decimal numbers / spaces, apply the multiplicator, and rebuild the string.

Comment: A string exists of characters, not numbers. You'll need to parse the numbers from the string, multiply them and rebuild the string.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. To better understanding the problem, I added more inforamtions.

Comment: also, note that in SVG [Superfluous white space and *separators such as commas* can be eliminated](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just give the path a scale(2) transform, much simpler.

Comment: Paths have flags in them that must be 0 or 1. If you naively multiply all the values by two and the path has a flag in it that is non-zero then the path will become invalid.

Comment: I know that SVG paths can be build on different ways. But I use exactly the structure given above, without flags and so on. @Robert Longson Where should I give the path a scale(2) transform?

Comment: Add transform="scale(2)" to the path as an attribute

Comment: @RobertLongson I can just use the 'd="(path data)"' from the path, just a string with the moveto, line, curve, and so on information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun I did a universal function with linq:

```
public string MultiplyNumbersInString(string text, int multiplier)
{
    double n;
    return string.Join(" ",
        (from t in text.Split(' ')
         select (double.TryParse(t, out n) 
            ? (double.Parse(t) * multiplier).ToString("F") 
            : t))
        .ToList());
    }
}
```

You can provide string you would like to change and a multiplier and it will change your string accordingly. You can call it like this

```
string originalText = "M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z";
string newText = MultiplyNumbersInString(originalText, 2);
```

**EDIT:**

@CPA After reading your comment and your rejected edit of my answer, here are two functions that will do what you want.

First one using lamdas is the one you wrote in rejected edit:

```
public string MultiplyNumbersInString(string text, int multiplier)
{
    return string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ')
                            .Select(t1 => (t1.Contains(',')) 
                            ? (string.Join(",", t1.Split(',')
                            .Select(t2 => (double.Parse(t2) * multiplier).ToString()))) 
                            : t1)); 
}
```

And here is my function without lamdas

```
public string MultiplyNumbersInString(string text, int multiplier)
{
    return string.Join(" ", (from t in text.Split(' ')
                             select (t.Contains(",")
                             ? string.Join(",",
                                (from t1 in t.Split(',')
                                 select (double.Parse(t1) * multiplier).ToString()))
                             : t)).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Your solution is nice and simple. But it doesn't  work with numbers which are bigger than 99.

Comment: @CPA it does work. For example: for string "M 0,20 110,20 40,80 0,80 z" it returns "M 0,40 220,40 81,60 1,60 z". What string are you passing to the function

Comment: And if the path has a flag of value 1 this makes the path invalid.

Comment: @Maco Sorry, my I expect my explanation was not clear. "0,20" - there two numbers instead of one comma separated number.

Answer (score 1):

Assume we have a string like this.

```
var d = "M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z";
```

We want to multiply all numbers int it by 2. We use an overload of`Regex.Replace` function which takes a string, a function that will be applied on each match that have been found and replace the match with the value returned by this function.

in the function we try to parse the matched string with our pattern to string, if it succeed the we double it and return, and if it failed we return the original matched string.

```
d = Regex.Replace(d, "([0-9]{0,})", (m) =>
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(m.Value, out i))
    {
        return (2*i).ToString();
    }
    return m.Value;
}, RegexOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread. Try "80, 90" though, which will become "160, 1160". Replacing isn't safe.

Comment: `d` is a *SWG path*; so the solution should accept *any* SWG e.g. `"M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"`for which the implementation doesn't double the values

Comment: And if the path has a flag of value 1 this makes the path invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For my own entertainement, here is one answer.

```
var d = "M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z";
var split = d.Split(' ');

string result = string.Empty;

foreach (var element in split)
{
    if (element.Contains(","))
    {
        var couple = element.Split(',');
        int val1, val2;

        bool isNum = int.TryParse(couple[0], out val1);
        isNum &= int.TryParse(couple[1], out val2);

        if (isNum) // could be removed and simplified if there are never "," between something else than two numbers
        {
            result += " " + (val1 * 2).ToString() + "," + (val2 * 2).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            result += " " + element;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result += " " + element;
    }
}

result = result.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Simplified version (no type check, will throw exceptions if there is something else than a number around the commas) :

```
var d = "M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z";
var split = d.Split(' ');

string result = string.Empty;

foreach (var element in split)
{
    if (element.Contains(","))
    {
        var couple = element.Split(',');
        int val1 = int.Parse(couple[0]);
        int val2 = int.Parse(couple[1]);

        result += " " + (val1 * 2).ToString() + "," + (val2 * 2).ToString();                
    }
    else
    {
        result += " " + element;
    }
}
result = result.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: "if (isNum) // could be removed and simplified if there are never "," between something else than two numbers" - The "," is just between two numbers.

Comment: Your question wasn't clear, this is why I handle all cases. Then you can simplify this a few : remove the ".TryParse" boolean output check, remove the if around the result building and delete the first "else" part. Etc. I just suggested code to help you to figure out how you can achieve your goal, but at the end it's up to you to do whatever you want...

Comment: Hmm, your first method isn't right - the numbers aren't "decimals with a comma" (i.e. 0,5 isn't a half) but are pairs of coordinates on an X,Y plane - 0,5 means move to a point at x=0, y=5, so doubling it should yield 0,10 and not 1,0.

Comment: I was very clear about the two possible interpretations of the OP question and, thus, what each implementation does.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid > I see first post was edited, so what the OP wants is now a bit clearer. I removed my "first" proposal which is not relevant. I have also added the simplified version of the second one.

Comment: And if the path has a flag of value 1 this makes the path invalid.

Comment: Tell this to the OP ;). I'm just answering to its question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
List<double> myList = Regex.Replace("M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z", @"[^\d\, ]", "").Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToList<String>().ConvertAll(item => double.Parse(item)*2);
```

to return a string just use

```
  String Str= String.Join(" ", (Regex.Replace("M 0,20 40,20 40,80 0,80 z", @"[^\d\, ]", "").Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToList<String>().ConvertAll(item => (double.Parse(item)*2).ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Comment: this is returning list of doubles not the string which it's numbers are doubled.

Comment: here is the result as a string if you prefer it ;-)

Comment: and the result is totally different from what OP wants.

Comment: And if the path has a flag of value 1 this makes the path invalid.